# how to convert filled pdf to fdf or xfdf file in c#

Tags: xml, pdf, fdf, xfdf

How to convert filled `pdf` to `xml` or `fdf` or `xdfd` file which is designed in `Adobe livecycle designer 7.1` Starting point is most appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for your task.

The library can export forms data in FDF format. It only requires couple of lines of code

```
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("form.pdf"))
{
    pdf.ExportFdf("ExportedFdfData.fdf");
}
```

Disclaimer: I work as one of the developers of the library.

Comment: Can u explain me in detail " Docotic.pdf library ".because i am new to this.